# Change of variables in the integral definition of Bessel function

Tags: bessel-functions

I am trying to understand [Chapter 1 of "Advances in IMaging and Electron Pysics](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Natalie-Baddour/publication/241069465_Two-Dimensional_Fourier_Transforms_in_Polar_Coordinates/links/59db6ecaa6fdcc0ffd1a9f72/Two-Dimensional-Fourier-Transforms-in-Polar-Coordinates.pdf) and came across the following derivations:

> The 2D Fourier transform of a radially symmetric function ($f(r,\theta)=f(r))$ is given by$$F(\rho, \psi) = \int_{0}^{\infty} rf(r) dr \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ir\rho\cos(\psi-\theta)} d\theta$$
> Using the integral definition of the zeroth-order Bessel function,
> $$J_0(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ixcos(\psi-\theta)}d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ix\cos{\alpha}} d\alpha$$
> Therefore, the first equation can be written as
> $$F(\rho) = 2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} f(r) J_0(\rho r) rdr$$

In the second equation, it seems like we used the change of variables ($\alpha = \psi-\theta$) but why don't we have to change the integral range? Doesn't it have to be $\alpha: \psi-\pi \rightarrow \psi+\pi$ ?