# How to use the Parseval's theorem to show this relationship?

Tags: fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

**Problem**

My goal is to show the following relationship holds:
$$
\mathcal{S} \triangleq \frac{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(x,y)e^{j\phi(x,y)}dxdy}
{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(x,y) dx dy}
=\frac{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}(f_x, f_y) df_x df_y}
{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}_0(f_x, f_y) df_x df_y} \tag{1}\label{eq:goal}
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{H}(f_x, f_y)= \mathcal{F}\{h(u,v)\} \tag{2}\label{eq:H}\\
\mathcal{H}_0(f_x,f_y)= \mathcal{F}\{h_0(u,v)\}
$$
Note that
$$
h(u,v) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2z^2}\left|\mathcal{F}\{P(x,y)e^{j\phi(x,y)}\}_{f_x=\frac{u}{\lambda z}, f_y=\frac{v}{\lambda z}} \right|^2 \\
h_0(u,v) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2z^2}\left|\mathcal{F}\{P(x,y)\}_{f_x=\frac{u}{\lambda z}, f_y=\frac{v}{\lambda z}} \right|^2 \tag{3}\label{eq:h}
$$

---

**My attempt**

First, I simply substitute \eqref{eq:h} into \eqref{eq:H} to get
$$
\mathcal{H}(f_x, f_y)= \frac{1}{\lambda^2z^2}\mathcal{F}\left\{\left|\mathcal{F}\{P(x,y)e^{j\phi(x,y)}\}_{f_x=\frac{u}{\lambda z}, f_y=\frac{v}{\lambda z}} \right|^2\right\}\\
\mathcal{H}_0(f_x, f_y)= \frac{1}{\lambda^2z^2}\mathcal{F}\left\{\left|\mathcal{F}\{P(x,y)\}_{f_x=\frac{u}{\lambda z}, f_y=\frac{v}{\lambda z}} \right|^2\right\} \tag{4}\label{eq:H_simplify}
$$
I'd like to somehow reshape the RHS of \eqref{eq:goal} into LHS of \eqref{eq:goal}. So, using \eqref{eq:H_simplify}, it follows that
$$
\frac{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}(f_x, f_y) df_x df_y}
{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}_0(f_x, f_y) df_x df_y}
=\frac{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}\left\{\left|\mathcal{F}\{P(x,y)e^{j\phi(x,y)}\}_{f_x=\frac{u}{\lambda z}, f_y=\frac{v}{\lambda z}} \right|^2\right\}df_x df_y}
{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}\left\{\left|\mathcal{F}\{P(x,y)\}_{f_x=\frac{u}{\lambda z}, f_y=\frac{v}{\lambda z}} \right|^2\right\}df_x df_y}\tag{5}\label{end}
$$
The remaining task is to somehow show the following relationship:
$$
\frac{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}\left\{\left|\mathcal{F}\{P(x,y)e^{j\phi(x,y)}\}_{f_x=\frac{u}{\lambda z}, f_y=\frac{v}{\lambda z}} \right|^2\right\}df_x df_y}
{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}\left\{\left|\mathcal{F}\{P(x,y)\}_{f_x=\frac{u}{\lambda z}, f_y=\frac{v}{\lambda z}} \right|^2\right\}df_x df_y}
=\frac{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(x,y)e^{j\phi(x,y)}dxdy}
{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(x,y) dx dy}\tag{6}\label{wannashow}
$$
but I have no idea how to proceed. I'm sure I need to use the Parseval's theorem in some way but the first thing is to simplify \eqref{end} in some way. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Any luck? If you've solved it or at least made some progress, it's always okay to post an answer to your own question, even if it's a partial answer. Same comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4309816/284619) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4246902/284619) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/80847/25659) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/78666/25659) (I dream of an Optics and Photonics SE site some day, optics questions often just get lost in Physics SE)